# Why is onResume() not called for Activity after back button press, and what is a good workaround?

Tags: android, android-activity

In my MainActivity, I perform a few checks first to ensure the app is set up properly. I check to make sure some initialization data is downloaded from the server, and the user has selected their options. This needs to happen before they can actually begin using the app. Once they've set it up, it goes straight into normal behavior.

If they aren't properly initialized, a new Intent is fired to download the data, then another intent is fired to send them to an activity to make their selections. The problem is if they press the back button in this process. They return back to the MainActivity, but it isn't in a state to be displayed yet - it's just a blank screen. It should display the empty view of it's ListView, but since the fragment doesn't seem to be reloaded (or loaded in the first place), this doesn't happen.

I have a checkSetup() which should send them back to the stage of the set up process they still need to complete, but I can't get it to fire. I thought that by putting this in onResume() it would be executed anytime the activity was resumed, but onResume() does not seem to be fired when the activity is resumed from the back stack. I've also tried onRestart() as well with no luck.

There's plenty of documentation of what happens to the activity being killed on a back press, but scant info (that I've found) on what, if anything, happens in the activity being returned to.

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity  {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        SyncAdapter.initializeSyncAdapter(this);
    }

    private void loadFragment(){
        MyFragment myFragment =  ((MyFragment)getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_1));
        if (myFragment == null) {
            myFragment = new MyFragment();
        }
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_1, myFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onContentChanged() {
        super.onContentChanged();
        View empty = findViewById(R.id.empty);
        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        list.setEmptyView(empty);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        checkSetup();
        loadFragment();
    }

    void checkSetup(){
        //do some checks
    }
}
```

I've also tried setting the MainActivity to both `singleTop` and `singleTask` in the manifest, which hasn't helped either.

How can I have the Activity either restart completely, or call something when it is returned to on a back press if onResume() is never called. And why would onResume() not be called here, since it is, in fact, resuming?

**UPDATE**: 
For clarification, the other activities called in the sequence can also be called in the normal operation of the application, so they are not only used in the initialization process.

To put it more concretely:

- a list of supported languages is downloaded from the server. This is the first thing that should happen, and should only happen on the first run. But it's checked for every time, in case the user wipes data, etc.
- the user then selects the various languages they would like to install / download. This has to happen on the install, but they can then choose to add / remove languages later, so it is not only used in the setup process.
- The user then chooses their active language. This happens in both the setup and at any other point.

In the setup process, each of these activities runs the checkSetup() method and directs to the intent appropriate for the current state. If the home button is pressed at any point, it works as it should. The problem is when the back button is pressed, as it returns to MainActivity and checkSetup() is never called.

I would prefer to NOT disable the back button, as at any other point, it can be used correctly.

**UPDATE 2**: 
As a work around, I've added checkSetup() calls to onBackPressed() for all of the other activities, but this seems like a poor design. I am redundantly calling that method (in onBackPressed() in the Activity that is ending, and then in onResume() in the MainActivity) for any back button press. In addition, logic- and design-wise, it is poor. Checking the setup has nothing to do with leaving the other activities; it is only relevant to the entry points of a handful of activities, and should only take place there.

So, I've got it working, but would love a cleaner solution if anyone has suggestions. Or, can anyone explain why onResume() is not called here. Reading other related posts, the first suggestion everyone has is "use onResume()," as this would make sense. According the the Android life cycle diagrams and the documentation, onResume() is called right before the Activity is made visible, and I haven't seen an exception to this noted in any official capacity - just in anecdotal evidence from people wrestling with this issue. So, is this a bug or a feature? Is the documentation just shoddy, or am I missing something?

Comment: Did you try to override the back button call? Either you override it doing nothing (instead of navigating backwards) or you trigger the activity / fragments you would like to show here)
`@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // do something or just prevent back button pressing
}`

Comment: My understanding of onBackPressed() is that it is triggered in the Activity on the top of the stack. Thus I would have to override it on each of the Activities down the line that could call it. And then I'd have to do some conditional stuff based on whether the MainActivity was completely setup, which just seems clunky and unwieldy.

Comment: Seperate logic and data in application. Best way to do it , create a singleton claas that handles processes or services whatever you call. OnCreate method create ui , onResume method fetch data from singleton class.

Comment: @AbdullahTellioglu I'm not sure I see how that really helps; onResume doesn't get called when resuming on a back button press.

Comment: I'm glad onBackPressed helped you to fix your problem. To improve your design, how about using a config.xml to store the initial process state? You could set multiple checkmarks for each step or a counter variable. However, as a result you should set some boolean variable like IS_INITIAL_PROCESS_COMPLETED to true or so. Then in your onBackPressed method you simply check this variable and you would call your checkSetup() method in case it is not set to true. Hope this helps. Let me know if I should put this as answer below.

Comment: Try adding it in onCreate

Answer (score -1):

because the activity not stop or  destroy ,
you can test the onPause(); onStop();
i think  ,if you know  what active  is running  you will know  what to do 
 good luck